# How to define rule for sum data values in Protege?

Tags: owl, protege, swrl

If I want to sum the cases of European countries in individual Europe is it possible to make it with SWRL rule in Protege

Comment: Check [`sqwrlb:sum()`](https://github.com/protegeproject/swrlapi/wiki/SQWRLCore#Aggregation). That will be a query, not a rule.

Comment: Thank you. This was useful. The query generate the result.